# Mapei Aqua Defense Repair

Tags: shower, tile, waterproofing, grout

I used Mapei's aqua defense to waterproof my shower curb, floor and walls after gutting the shower, and redoing the curb, shower floor mud bed and hanging new durock.

So far I've only installed the pebble floor tile (no grout or wall tile). Due to a mistake, I may have to remove the floor tile. If I do I will damage the waterproofing over the mud bed.

Can I paint another coat or 2 of aqua defense over the top of the existing waterproofing after I remove the floor tile?

I posted yesterday about letting the tile sealant drop on the sides and edges of the pebble tile while pre-sealing before grouting.

I think it'll be very difficult (if not impossible) to clean off the sealant from all the nooks and crannies and get good grout adhesion now. It's a bone headed mistake. What to go from here?!?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I never had a chance to address your previous question but if it were me I would not pull up the tiles because of the grout sealer concern. Just grout it and hope for the best; I don't think it's an issue there's no reason for that grout to **not** stay in place and it's really only decorative.

Comment: What does the manufacturer say about doing spot repairs? Do they recommend removal, recoat the entire thing, recoat only the damaged areas? I'll bet they've dealt with this before and can provide you a _great_ answer that you could post as an answer to your own question to help others.